# How to get the global_step when restoring checkpoints in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm saving my session state like so:

```
self._saver = tf.saver()
self._saver.save(self._session, '/network', global_step=self._time)
```

When I later restore I want to get the value of the global_step for the checkpoint I restore from. This is in order to set some hyper parameters from it.

The hacky way to do this would be to run through and parse the file names in the checkpoint directory. But surly there has to be a better, built in way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

General pattern is to have a `global_step` variable to keep track of steps

```
global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
```

Then you can save with

```
saver.save(sess, save_path, global_step=global_step)
```

When you restore, the value of `global_step` is restored as well

Comment: This is not working, everytime I resume training the global_step variable is reset to 0

Comment: this would mean that global_step you are saving to checkpoint is 0, or you are reinitializing it to 0 after restoring it

Comment: This would be a good solution, but if `saver.restore` can return the global_step, it would be simple. We can just do 'global_step=saver.restore(...)' Do you think the tensorflow team might be interested in this direction?

Comment: Seems like it could useful in some cases, but also seems like a lot of work -- now that TF 1.0 is out, any changes to API have to go through API review

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov This does not work for inception v3 training here : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception/inception the global step is always 0 after restoring a model.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bit of a hack, but the other answers did not work for me at all

```
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_dir) 

#Extract from checkpoint filename
step = int(os.path.basename(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path).split('-')[1])
```

**Update 9/2017**

I'm not sure if this started working due to updates, but the following method seems to be effective in getting global_step to update and load properly:

Create two ops. One to hold global_step and another to increment it:

```
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='global_step')
    increment_global_step = tf.assign_add(global_step,1,
                                            name = 'increment_global_step')
```

Now in your training loop run the increment op every time you run your training op.

```
sess.run([train_op,increment_global_step],feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

If you ever want to retrieve you global step value as an integer at any point, just use the following command after loading the model:

```
sess.run(global_step)
```

This can be useful for creating filenames or calculating what your current epoch is without having a second tensorflow Variable for holding that value. For instance, calculating the current epoch on loading would be something like:

```
loaded_epoch = sess.run(global_step)//(batch_size*num_train_records)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as Lawrence Du, I could not find a way to get the global_step by restoring the model. So I applied [his hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43690580/889617) to [the inception v3 training code in the Tensorflow/models github repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/inception/inception/inception_train.py) I'm using. The code below also contains a fix related to the `pretrained_model_checkpoint_path`.

If you have a better solution, or know what I'm missing please leave a comment!

In any case, this code works for me:

```
...

# When not restoring start at 0
last_step = 0
if FLAGS.pretrained_model_checkpoint_path:
    # A model consists of three files, use the base name of the model in
    # the checkpoint path. E.g. my-model-path/model.ckpt-291500
    #
    # Because we need to give the base name you can't assert (will always fail)
    # assert tf.gfile.Exists(FLAGS.pretrained_model_checkpoint_path)

    variables_to_restore = tf.get_collection(
        slim.variables.VARIABLES_TO_RESTORE)
    restorer = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
    restorer.restore(sess, FLAGS.pretrained_model_checkpoint_path)
    print('%s: Pre-trained model restored from %s' %
          (datetime.now(), FLAGS.pretrained_model_checkpoint_path))

    # HACK : global step is not restored for some unknown reason
    last_step = int(os.path.basename(FLAGS.pretrained_model_checkpoint_path).split('-')[1])

    # assign to global step
    sess.run(global_step.assign(last_step))

...

for step in range(last_step + 1, FLAGS.max_steps):

  ...
```

Comment: This method does not work for the official pretrained inception v3 model checkpoint made available at (http://download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_v3_2016_08_28.tar.gz) as the checkpoint filename only consists of inception_v3.ckpt

Comment: @VipinPillai In all pretrained models the global step is reset to zero. So this models can be used to initialize the graph for finetuning without setting the global step.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `global_step` variable to keep track of steps, but if in your code, you are initializing or assigning this value to another `step` variable, it may not be consistent.

For instance, you define your `global_step` using:

```
global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
```

Assign to your training operation:

```
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
```

Save in your checkpoint:

```
saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=global_step)
```

And restore from your checkpoint:

```
saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path)
```

the value of `global_step` is restored as well but if you are assigning it to another variable, say `step`, then you must do something like:

```
step = global_step.eval(session=sess)
```

The variable `step`, contains the last saved `global_step` in the checkpoint.

It will be nice to also define the global_step from graph than as zero variable (as earlier defined):

```
global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
```

This will get your last `global_step` if exist or create one if not.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution that I saw on this matter! +1.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

As tensorflow variable (will be evaluated in the session)

```python
global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
# use global_step variable to calculate your hyperparameter 
# this variable will be evaluated later in the session
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # restore all variables from checkpoint
    saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path)
    # than init table and local variables and start training/evaluation ...
```

**Or:** As numpy integer (without any session):

```python
reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader(absolute_checkpoint_path)
global_step = reader.get_tensor('global_step')
```

## Long Answer

There are at least two ways retrieving the global from a checkpoint. As tensorflow variable or as numpy integer. Parsing the filename will not work, if the `global_step` was not provided as a parameter in the [`save`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#save) method of the `Saver`. For pretrained models see the remark at the end of the answer.

## As Tensorflow variable

If you need the `global_step` variable to calculate some hyperparameters you can just use [`tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/get_or_create_global_step). This will return a tensorflow variable. Because the variable will be evaluated later in the session you can only use tensorflow operations to calculate your hyperparameters. So e.g.: `max(global_step, 100)` will not work. You have to use tensorflow equivalent `tf.maximum(global_step, 100)` that can be evaluated later in the session.

Within the session you can initialize the global step variable with a checkpoint using [`saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#restore)

```python
global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
# use global_step variable to calculate your hyperparameter 
# this variable will be evaluated later in the session
hyper_parameter = tf.maximum(global_step, 100) 
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # restore all variables from checkpoint
    saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path)
    # than init table and local variables and start training/evaluation ...

    # for verification you can print the global step and your hyper parameter
    print(sess.run([global_step, hyper_parameter]))
```

## Or: As numpy integer (without session)

If you need the global step variable as scalar without starting a session you can also read this variable directly from your checkpoint file(s). You just need a `NewCheckpointReader`. Because of a [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4921) in older tensorflow versions you should convert the path of the checkpoint file to an absolute path. With the reader you can get all the tensors of the model as numpy variables. 
The name of the global step variable is a constant string [`tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_STEP`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys#GLOBAL_STEP) defined as `'global_step'`.

```python
absolute_checkpoint_path = os.path.abspath(checkpoint_path)
reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader(absolute_checkpoint_path)
global_step = reader.get_tensor(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_STEP)
```

**Remark to pretrained models:** In most pretrained models that are available online the global step is reset to zero. So, these models can be used to initialize the model parameters for finetuning without overwrite the global step.

Answer (score 0):

The current 0.10rc0 version seems to be different, there's no tf.saver() any more.  Now it's tf.train.Saver().  Also, the save command adds info onto save_path filename for the global_step, so we can't just call restore on the same save_path since that not the actual save file.

The easiest way I see right now is to use the SessionManager along with a saver like this:

```
my_checkpoint_dir = "/tmp/checkpoint_dir"
# make a saver to use with SessionManager for restoring
saver = tf.train.Saver()
# Build an initialization operation to run below.
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
# use a SessionManager to help with automatic variable restoration
sm = tf.train.SessionManager()
# try to find the latest checkpoint in my_checkpoint_dir, then create a session with that restored
# if no such checkpoint, then call the init_op after creating a new session
sess = sm.prepare_session("", init_op=init, saver=saver, checkpoint_dir=my_checkpoint_dir))
```

That's it.  Now you have a session that's either restored from the my_checkpoint_dir (make sure that directory exists before calling this), or if there's no checkpoint there then it creates a new session and calls the init_op to initialize your variables.

When you want to save, you just save to any name you want in that directory and pass the global_step in.  Here's an example where I save the step variable in a loop as the global_step, so it comes back to that point if you kill the program and restart it so it restores the checkpoint:

```
checkpoint_path = os.path.join(my_checkpoint_dir, 'model.ckpt')
saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=step)
```

This creates files in my_checkpoint_dir like "model.ckpt-1000" where 1000 is the global_step passed in.  If it keeps running, then you get more like "model.ckpt-2000".  The SessionManager above picks up the latest one of these when the program is restarted.  The checkpoint_path can be whatever file name you want, as long as it's in the checkpoint_dir.  The save() will create that file with the global_step appended (as shown above).  It also creates a "checkpoint" index file, which is how the SessionManager then finds the latest save checkpoint.

Answer (score 0):

just note my solution on global step saving and restore.

Save:

```py
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='global_step')
saver.save(sess, model_path + model_name, global_step=_global_step)
```

Restore:

```py
if os.path.exists(model_path):
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))
    print("Model restore finished, current globle step: %d" % global_step.eval())
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that a variable is not restored as expected is most likely due to the fact that it was created after your `tf.Saver()` object was created.

The place where you create the `tf.Saver()` object matters when you don't explicitly specify a `var_list`, or specify `None` for `var_list`. The expected behavior for many programmers is that all variables in the graph are saved when the `save()` method is called, but this is not the case, and it should perhaps be documented as such. A snapshot of all variables in the graph is saved at the time of object creation.

Unless you're having any performance issues, it's safest to create the saver object right when you decide to save your progress. Otherwise, make sure to create the saver object after you create all your variables.

Also, the `global_step` that is passed to `saver.save(sess, save_path, global_step=global_step)` is merely a counter used for creating the filename and has nothing to do with whether it will be restored as a `global_step` variable. This is a parameter misnomer IMO since if you're saving your progress at the end of each epoch, it's probably best to pass your epoch number for this parameter.