# How to retrieve last global_step after saver.restore

Tags: tensorflow

We can save a check point

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, FLAGS.train_dir, global_step=step)
```

Then, later, I can restore all variables:

```
saver.restore(sess, FLAGS.train_dir)
```

I want to get the 'golbal_step' I passed when I call 'saver.save' so that I can continue the training based on the last global_step.

Is there any way to get it? It seems CheckpointState does not include the information.

```
message CheckpointState {
  // Path to the most-recent model checkpoint.
  string model_checkpoint_path = 1;

  // Paths to all not-yet-deleted model checkpoints, sorted from oldest to
  // newest.
  // Note that the value of model_checkpoint_path should be the last item in
  // this list.
  repeated string all_model_checkpoint_paths = 2;
}
```

Like [Tensorflow get the global_step when restoring checkpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113090), I can introduce a new TF variable, but it would be best if I can do it without adding a new variable.Is there any way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow get the global\_step when restoring checkpoints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113090/tensorflow-get-the-global-step-when-restoring-checkpoints)

Comment: @Daniel I don't think this is a duplicate since your reference does not answer how to restore, only how to save (facing the same problem as him).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple `sess.run(global_step)` should return the value.

```
## Create and Save global_step 
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(...).minimize(..., global_step=global_step, ...) 
...
saver = tf.train.Saver() # var_list is None: defaults to the list of all saveable objects.

## Restore global_step 
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
...
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FilePath_checkpoints)
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        last_global_step = sess.run(global_step)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    predict_top_5 = tf.nn.top_k(scores, k=5)
    label_top_5 = tf.nn.top_k(input_y, k=5)
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state('models')
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        saver.restore(sess,ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        global_step = int(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1])
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanations. Code only answers are often not too helpful.