# Tensorflow : Graph is finalized and cannot be modified

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to save variables through checkpoints to introduce fault tolerance to my program. I am trying to achieve this by using the MonitoredTrainingSession function. The following is my configuration:-

```
import tensorflow as tf

global_step = tf.Variable(10, trainable=False, name='global_step')
x = tf.constant(2)

with tf.device("/job:local/task:0"):
    y1 = tf.Variable(x + 300)

with tf.device("/job:local/task:1"):
    y2 = tf.Variable(x**2)

with tf.device("/job:local/task:2"):
    y3 = tf.Variable(5*x)

with tf.device("/job:local/task:3"):
    y0 = tf.Variable(x - 66)
    y = y0 + y1 + y2 + y3

model = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver(sharded=True)

chief = tf.train.ChiefSessionCreator(scaffold=None, master='grpc://localhost:2222', config=None, checkpoint_dir='/home/tensorflow/codes/checkpoints')
summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(save_steps=None, save_secs=10, output_dir='/home/tensorflow/codes/savepoints', summary_writer=None, scaffold=None, summary_op=tf.summary.tensor_summary(name="y", tensor=y))
saver_hook = tf.train.CheckpointSaverHook(checkpoint_dir='/home/tensorflow/codes/checkpoints', save_secs=None, save_steps=True, saver=saver, checkpoint_basename='model.ckpt', scaffold=None)

# with tf.train.MonitoredSession(session_creator=ChiefSessionCreator,hooks=[saver_hook, summary_hook]) as sess:

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master='grpc://localhost:2222', is_chief=True, checkpoint_dir='/home/tensorflow/codes/checkpoints',
    scaffold=None, hooks=[saver_hook,summary_hook], chief_only_hooks=None, save_checkpoint_secs=None, save_summaries_steps=True, config=None) as sess:

    while not sess.should_stop():
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    while not sess.should_stop():
        result = sess.run(y)
        print(result)
```

I get the following **RuntimeError** which I am unable to resolve:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "add_1.py", line 39, in <module>
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 1187, in global_variables_initializer
    return variables_initializer(global_variables())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 1169, in variables_initializer
    return control_flow_ops.group(*[v.initializer for v in var_list], name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2773, in group
    deps.append(_GroupControlDeps(dev, ops_on_device[dev]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2721, in _GroupControlDeps
    return no_op(name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_control_flow_ops.py", line 186, in no_op
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("NoOp", name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2199, in create_op
    self._check_not_finalized()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1925, in _check_not_finalized
    raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")
RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43325348/6521116

Comment: For anyone who has this problem and comes to check here, in addition to guinny's answer the question link provided by @KrisRoofe proved to be useful.

Answer (score 11):

The root cause for your error seems to be that MonitoredTrainingSession has finalized (frozen) the graph and your `tf.global_variable_initializer()` is no longer able to modify it.

Having said that, there are multiple things that require attention:

1) Why do you try to repeatedly initialize all variables here?

```
while not sess.should_stop():
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

2) It seems some of your code is already included in `MonitoredTrainingSession`, e.g. `ChiefSessionCreator`. Can you please take another look at the code (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py#L243) or search for its sample usage and see how `MonitoredTrainingSession` is supposed to be used?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new to tensorflow therefore my code may be very crude.
1) I have commented the while loop above the initialization part so that it runs only once.
2) I was not sure if the chiefsessioncreator is needed even after specifying the configuration in monitoredtrainingsesion.
It actually gave the output 252 in a loop when I ran. But when I stopped and ran it again, it showing this:- [http://pastebin.com/Cgk4Z9Pc](http://pastebin.com/Cgk4Z9Pc)

Comment: When you ran it the second time, it tries to load your checkpoint from an earlier run, which is missing the global_step. Check out this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113090/tensorflow-get-the-global-step-when-restoring-checkpoints) how to save and restore global_step. And here (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b00fc538638f87ac45be9105057b9865f0f9418b/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session_test.py#L206) how to initialize one.

Answer (score 10):

This may not be recommended for your use case, but it is possible to [unfinalize a Graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/48d13f510b70e48b61a435011f78bfef4df55c9b/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L3122-L3130):

```
sess.graph._unsafe_unfinalize()
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to initialize the graph on loop, you can use the function to create new graph on top of loop.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.Graph().as_default()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your aim is to use `MonitoredTrainingSession` to get you checkpointing, the usage is much simpler than your example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()
x = tf.constant(2)
y1 = x + 300
y2 = x**2
y3 = x * 5
y0 = x - 66
y = y0 + y1 + y2 + y3
step = tf.assign_add(global_step, 1)

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(checkpoint_dir='/tmp/checkpoints') as sess:
    while not sess.should_stop():
        result, i = sess.run([y, step])
        print(result, i)
```

- The hooks for saving/restoring checkpoints are created by `MonitoredTrainingSession` for you.
- If you pass in `save_checkpoint_secs` you can change the frequency of checkpointing from the 10 minute default. I find a higher frequency isn't worth it: saving checkpoints isn't free, so very frequent checkpointing will end up slowing training down.
- The `ChiefSessionCreator` and gRPC config is only needed for distributed running (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) for a description of the concepts. Similarly with assigning ops to specific devices - make sure you really need to do this before using it as it can slow things down if you're not careful.
- You don't need to wrap the result of operations on tensors with `tf.Variable()` - they already are variables.
- You can pass `save_summaries_steps` for monitoring training with tensorboard, but by default that'll happen every 100 steps anyway.