# TensorFlow supervisor prevents variable assignment: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified

Tags: python, tensorflow

This code works fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable(initial_value=0)

with tf.Session() as session:
    print session.run(x.assign(1))
```

But this code fails:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable(initial_value=0)
supervisor = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir="/tmp")

with tf.Session() as session:
    print session.run(x.assign(1))
```

The only difference is the instantiation of a `tf.train.Supervisor`. Note that we don't even use the supervisor to create a managed session.

The error is:

```
python tf_supervisor_freeze.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf_supervisor_freeze.py", line 6, in <module>
    print session.run(x.assign(1))
  File "<virtual_env_path>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 522, in assign
    return state_ops.assign(self._variable, value, use_locking=use_locking)
  File "<virtual_env_path>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_state_ops.py", line 47, in assign
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "<virtual_env_path>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 491, in apply_op
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "<virtual_env_path>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 702, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "<virtual_env_path>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 110, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "<virtual_env_path>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 103, in constant
    attrs={"value": tensor_value, "dtype": dtype_value}, name=name).outputs[0]
  File "<virtual_env_path>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2286, in create_op
    self._check_not_finalized()
  File "<virtual_env_path>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2009, in _check_not_finalized
    raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")
RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Error remains if `tf.train.Supervisor(logdir="/tmp", summary_op=None, saver=None)` is used to disable some of the supervisor's services.

This problem was raised by somebody else on [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8235) but no answer was provided there; the request was to raise the issue on StackOverflow instead. The only relevant [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41798311/tensorflow-graph-is-finalized-and-cannot-be-modified) does not appear to address this specific case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as the error says, you cannot modify the graph when the graph is finalized.

> RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")

When execute this code `tf.train.Supervisor()`, the graph will be finalized. You can check code of it with path /tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py in tensorflow of version 1.0.

And you will find this:

```
# The graph is not allowed to change anymore.
graph.finalize()
```

So you cannot modify the graph after `Supervisor()`.

Answer (score 3):

I can't explain why but I've found a work-around. This works:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable(initial_value=0)
a = x.assign(1)
supervisor = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir="/tmp")

with tf.Session() as session:
    print session.run(a)
```

All that has been done is to move the creation of the assignment operation to before the creation of the supervisor (i.e. `a = x.assign(1)`). It appears the supervisor really does freeze the graph preventing one from creating, or more accurately using, new operations after the supervisor's creation.

Comment: but why he hell is this so? i mean, finalization makes it impossible to, say, freeze a graph and save it to disk. :(

Answer (score 2):

An assign operation is a new operation in the Graph.
If that operation is defined before Graph finalization (even if executed later), then it's OK.

Executing the operation effectively assigns a value to the variable. This can safely be done after Graph finalization, as it doesn't change the graph.

Bottomline is:
- declare the ops before graph finalization
- run them after.