# Determining what is modifying a TensorFlow Graph

Tags: tensorflow

I'm attempting to use a `tf.train.Supervisor()`, but I'm receiving the following error: `RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.`

The problem is clearly that I'm modifying my graph after instantiating a supervisor (and confirmed by [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324923/tensorflow-supervisor-prevents-variable-assignment-graph-is-finalized-and-canno/43325348#43325348)), but it doesn't tell me **how** to find where I'm modifying my graph. I've been through my code and nothing looks like an obvious culprit, although in another question I posted, I found out that `.minimize()` alters the graph, so I'm likely making a similar mistake.

Here's my code. However, while I'm interested in finding my bug, I'm also interested in learning how one can generally solve this problem.

```
tf.set_random_seed(seed=0)
supervisor = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=tf.flags.FLAGS.log_dir,
                                 global_step=model.global_step)

# create coordinator to handle threading
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()

supervisor = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=tf.flags.FLAGS.log_dir,
                                 global_step=global_step)

with supervisor.managed_session() as sess:

    # start threads to enqueue input minibatches for training
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    # initialize all variables and ops
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    start_time = time.time()

    # train
    for step in range(1, tf.flags.FLAGS.training_steps + 1):

        # check for any raised exceptions
        if supervisor.should_stop():
            break

        train_op(sess, model, x_train, y_train, y_lengths_train)

        # every 100 steps, evaluate model metrics and write summaries to disk
        if step % 10 == 0 or step == tf.flags.FLAGS.training_steps:
            eval_op(sess, model, x_valid, y_valid, y_lengths_valid, start_time)
            start_time = time.time()

    # when done, ask the threads to stop
    coord.request_stop()

    # wait for threads to finish
    coord.join(threads)
```

Here is the code for my `train_op:

```
def train_op(sess, model, x_minibatch, y_minibatch, y_lengths_minibatch):
    """
    Training operation(s) for model.
    """

    # dequeue training data
    x_values, y_values, y_lengths_values = sess.run([x_minibatch, y_minibatch, y_lengths_minibatch])

    # permute training data for robustness
    x_values, y_values = permute_values(x_values, y_values)

    # minimize loss
    sess.run([model.train_op], feed_dict={model.x: x_values,
                                      model.y_actual: y_values,
                                      model.y_actual_lengths: y_lengths_values})
```

And here is the code for my `eval_op`:

```
def eval_op(sess, model, x_minibatch, y_minibatch, y_lengths_minibatch, start_time):
    """
    Evaluation operation(s) for model.
    """

    x_values, y_values, y_lengths_values = sess.run([x_minibatch, y_minibatch, y_lengths_minibatch])

    loss, metrics, step = sess.run([model.loss, model.metrics, model.global_step],
                                   feed_dict={model.x: x_values,
                                          model.y_actual: y_values,
                                          model.y_actual_lengths: y_lengths_values})

    print('Step Number: {}\tLength of Y: {}'.format(step + 1, y_lengths_values))

    print('Elapsed time: {:.2f}\tLoss: {:.4f}\tAccuracy: {:.4f}'.format(time.time() - start_time, loss,
                                                                    metrics['accuracy']))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace that is printed with the `RuntimeError` ought to indicate what function is being called when the error arises.

However, based on your code, I suspect it is the call to [`tf.global_variables_initializer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables_initializer) that is adding a new op to your graph. Since you are using [`tf.train.Supervisor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Supervisor), it should not be necessary to call this, because the supervisor (by default) takes care of initializing your variables. You can therefore delete the line `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`.

Comment: Your suspicion was correct - thank you! And you were right about the stack trace - I just wasn't looking for enough up.